# AppleScript to determine if a shape has been warped or scaled

Tags: math, applescript

I'm making a script to determine if a shape has been warped or scaled. It starts by making a list of all the lengths of a line in one shape, like so.

```
set noofsides to text returned of (display dialog "Enter number of sides:" default answer "")

set sidevalues to {}
set repeatnumber to 0
repeat noofsides times
    set repeatnumber to repeatnumber + 1
    set currentsidevalue to text returned of (display dialog "Enter length of line " & repeatnumber & ":" default answer "")
    set the end of sidevalues to currentsidevalue
end repeat
```

It then does the same thing for the second, edited shape. This gives me two lists with different variables. To determine if the two shapes are similar, each 'before' line divided by each 'after' line has to be the same. For example, for a triangle:

```
firstline1/secondline1 = firstline2/secondline2 = firstline3/secondline3
```

Is there any way to quickly do this without having to do the following:

```
try
    set primevariable1 to first item of primesidevalues
    set primevariable2 to second item of primesidevalues
    set primevariable3 to third item of primesidevalues
    -- ...
end try

try
    set regularvariable1 to first item of sidevalues
    set regularvariable2 to second item of sidevalues
    set regularvariable3 to third item of sidevalues
    -- ...
end try

try
    variable4
on error
    set variable4 to ""
end try
if (regularvariable1 / primevariable1) = (regularvariable2 / primevariable2) and (regularvariable3 / primevariable3) = (regularvariable1 / primevariable1) and (regularvariable3 / primevariable3) = (regularvariable2 / primevariable2) and variable4 = "" then
    display dialog "Shape is similar"
end if
```

That is only for a 3 sided shape. If I wanted to do something with say, 5 or 6 sides, this would get increasingly long. Perhaps something like if dividing every number in list one divided by every number in list two all equal each other, then the shape is similar? Can anyone help?

Comment: Are there loops  and indexed variables (lists/arrays) in applescript?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not quite sure how this could be implemented here.

Comment: Seems `set sidevalues to {}` denotes that `sidevalues` is some indexed data structure

Comment: Yes, this will set sidevalues to a list formatted like {"3", "4", "6"}. Each item in this list can be split up and assigned to individual variables, as I have done with "set regularvariable1 to first item of sidevalues"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the value of (**the first item in the first list** `/` **the first item in the second list**), use a loop to compare the value of the others items, like this:

```
set sidevalues to my getSidesValue("Enter number of sides for the first shape:")
set primesidevalues to my getSidesValue("Enter number of sides for the second shape:")
set tc to count sidevalues
if tc = (count primesidevalues) then -- the number of items in the lists is the same  
    set isSimilar to true
    set thisVal to (item 1 of sidevalues) / (item 1 of primesidevalues) -- Get the value of the first item in the lists
    repeat with i from 2 to tc -- loop to compare the value of the others items
        if (item i of sidevalues) / (item i of primesidevalues) is not thisVal then -- not the same value
            set isSimilar to false
            exit repeat -- no need to continue
        end if
    end repeat
else
    set isSimilar to false
end if
isSimilar


on getSidesValue(t)
    set noofsides to text returned of (display dialog t default answer "")
    set l to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to noofsides
        set currentsidevalue to text returned of (display dialog "Enter length of line " & i & ":" default answer "")
        set the end of l to currentsidevalue
    end repeat
    return l
end getSidesValue
```